# Python - Finding string frequencies of list of strings in text file

Tags: python, string, text, frequency

I am trying to find all occurrences of strings in a text file, where each string is located on a new line in the file.

For example, an example file may look like this:

```
jump start
jump go
feet start
jump go
```

The target tally would be 1 for all strings, except for "jump go" would have 2

So far, I have been successful at finding individual word counts using this code:

```
import re
import collections
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()
words = re.findall(r'\w+',text)
counts = collections.Counter(words)
print(counts)
```

However, this only gives output like: jump = 3, start = 2, go = 2, feet = 1

Not sure if this matters, but the number of lines in the file will be around 5 million, with around 12,000 independent strings.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: read your file into a list where each line would be an individual element in the list. Then use counter

Comment: use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the regex, read the file as `words=f.readlines()` . You'll end up with a list of strings corresponding to each line. Then, build the counter from that list.

Comment: Fran Borcic, how would you do this same thing, but now each string is bound by parentheses "xxxxx" instead of being on a new line?

Comment: Got it: words = re.findall(r'\"(.*?)\"',text)

Comment: No need for the backslashes though. Also, be careful, because this won't match the string if it contains a newline.

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work:

```
import collections

lines = [line.strip() for line in open('results.txt')]
counts = collections.Counter(lines)
print counts
```

Output:

```
['Sam', 'sam', 'johm go', 'johm go', 'johm for']
Counter({'johm go': 2, 'sam': 1, 'Sam': 1, 'johm for': 1})
```

Comment: Not keeping reference to the file object to close it afterwards can cause some trouble.